# Building catkin workspace on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: ros, mavericks, macosx, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to **build the catkin workspace** on Mac OS X (ROS installation using Homebrew) and per the installation wiki,

> We will use the catkin_make_isolated
> command because there are both catkin
> and plain cmake packages in the base
> install, when developing on your
> catkin only workspaces you should use
> catkin/commands/catkin_make.
>
> Invoke catkin_make_isolated: "`$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`"

I tried doing that and after a bunch of packages names listed, I get an error message. It seems to be something related to CMake and CatKin but I'm new to this and I don't exactly know what's happening here.

Below is the message (flow) after I run the above command.

```
Poojas-MacBook-Pro:ros_catkin_ws voladoddi$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Base path: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated
Devel space: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated
Install space: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
Additional CMake Arguments: -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~  traversing 251 packages in topological order:
~~  - catkin
~~  - genmsg
~~  - gencpp
~~  - genlisp
~~  - genpy
~~  - angles
~~  - bfl (plain cmake)
~~  - bond_core
~~  - cmake_modules
~~  - common_msgs
~~  - common_tutorials
~~  - console_bridge (plain cmake)
~~  - class_loader
~~  - cpp_common
~~  - desktop
~~  - desktop_full
~~  - diagnostics
~~  - driver_common
~~  - eigen_stl_containers
~~  - executive_smach
~~  - gazebo_ros_pkgs
~~  - geometry
~~  - geometry_experimental
~~  - geometry_tutorials
~~  - image_common
~~  - image_pipeline
~~  - image_transport_plugins
~~  - laser_pipeline
~~  - media_export
~~  - message_generation
~~  - message_runtime
~~  - mk
~~  - mobile
~~  - navigation
~~  - nodelet_core
~~  - octomap (plain cmake)
~~  - opencv2 (plain cmake)
~~  - openslam_gmapping
~~  - orocos_kdl (plain cmake)
~~  - perception
~~  - perception_pcl
~~  - python_orocos_kdl (plain cmake)
~~  - qt_dotgraph
~~  - qt_gui
~~  - qt_gui_app
~~  - qt_gui_core
~~  - qt_gui_py_common
~~  - random_numbers
~~  - robot
~~  - robot_model
~~  - ros
~~  - ros_base
~~  - ros_comm
~~  - ros_full
~~  - ros_tutorials
~~  - rosbag_migration_rule
~~  - rosbash
~~  - rosboost_cfg
~~  - rosbuild
~~  - rosclean
~~  - roscpp_traits
~~  - roscreate
~~  - rosdoc_lite
~~  - rosgraph
~~  - roslang
~~  - roslint
~~  - roslisp
~~  - rosmake
~~  - rosmaster
~~  - rosmsg
~~  - rospack
~~  - roslib
~~  - rosparam
~~  - rospy
~~  - rosservice
~~  - rostime
~~  - roscpp_serialization
~~  - python_qt_binding
~~  - rosbag_storage
~~  - roslaunch
~~  - rosunit
~~  - rosconsole
~~  - pluginlib
~~  - qt_gui_cpp
~~  - resource_retriever
~~  - rosconsole_bridge
~~  - rostest
~~  - rqt_action
~~  - rqt_bag
~~  - rqt_bag_plugins
~~  - rqt_common_plugins
~~  - rqt_console
~~  - rqt_dep
~~  - rqt_graph
~~  - rqt_gui
~~  - rqt_logger_level
~~  - rqt_moveit
~~  - rqt_msg
~~  - rqt_nav_view
~~  - rqt_plot
~~  - rqt_pose_view
~~  - rqt_publisher
~~  - rqt_py_common
~~  - rqt_py_console
~~  - rqt_reconfigure
~~  - rqt_robot_dashboard
~~  - rqt_robot_monitor
~~  - rqt_robot_plugins
~~  - rqt_robot_steering
~~  - rqt_runtime_monitor
~~  - rqt_service_caller
~~  - rqt_shell
~~  - rqt_srv
~~  - rqt_tf_tree
~~  - rqt_top
~~  - rqt_topic
~~  - rqt_web
~~  - simulators
~~  - smach
~~  - smclib
~~  - stage (plain cmake)
~~  - std_msgs
~~  - actionlib_msgs
~~  - bond
~~  - diagnostic_msgs
~~  - geometry_msgs
~~  - eigen_conversions
~~  - kdl_conversions
~~  - nav_msgs
~~  - rosgraph_msgs
~~  - sensor_msgs
~~  - camera_calibration_parsers
~~  - cv_bridge
~~  - image_geometry
~~  - map_msgs
~~  - pcl_msgs
~~  - shape_msgs
~~  - smach_msgs
~~  - std_srvs
~~  - stereo_msgs
~~  - tf2_msgs
~~  - tf2
~~  - tf2_bullet
~~  - trajectory_msgs
~~  - control_msgs
~~  - gazebo_msgs
~~  - urdfdom_headers (plain cmake)
~~  - urdf_parser_plugin
~~  - urdfdom (plain cmake)
~~  - vision_opencv
~~  - visualization_msgs
~~  - shape_tools
~~  - geometric_shapes
~~  - visualization_tutorials
~~  - viz
~~  - xmlrpcpp
~~  - roscpp
~~  - bondcpp
~~  - bondpy
~~  - collada_parser
~~  - diagnostic_common_diagnostics
~~  - joint_state_publisher
~~  - move_base_msgs
~~  - nodelet
~~  - nodelet_tutorial_math
~~  - pcl_conversions
~~  - pluginlib_tutorials
~~  - roscpp_tutorials
~~  - rosout
~~  - camera_calibration
~~  - diagnostic_aggregator
~~  - diagnostic_updater
~~  - dynamic_reconfigure
~~  - filters
~~  - message_filters
~~  - image_transport
~~  - camera_info_manager
~~  - image_view
~~  - polled_camera
~~  - rosnode
~~  - rospy_tutorials
~~  - rostopic
~~  - roswtf
~~  - rqt_gui_cpp
~~  - rqt_gui_py
~~  - rqt_image_view
~~  - self_test
~~  - smach_ros
~~  - tf2_py
~~  - timestamp_tools
~~  - topic_tools
~~  - rosbag
~~  - actionlib
~~  - actionlib_tutorials
~~  - diagnostic_analysis
~~  - driver_base
~~  - image_proc
~~  - nodelet_topic_tools
~~  - rqt_launch
~~  - stereo_image_proc
~~  - tf2_ros
~~  - tf
~~  - compressed_depth_image_transport
~~  - compressed_image_transport
~~  - fake_localization
~~  - gmapping
~~  - interactive_markers
~~  - interactive_marker_tutorials
~~  - laser_geometry
~~  - laser_assembler
~~  - laser_filters
~~  - map_server
~~  - amcl
~~  - pcl_ros
~~  - depth_image_proc
~~  - robot_pose_ekf
~~  - stage_ros
~~  - tf2_geometry_msgs
~~  - tf2_kdl
~~  - tf2_tools
~~  - tf_conversions
~~  - image_rotate
~~  - theora_image_transport
~~  - turtlesim
~~  - turtle_actionlib
~~  - turtle_tf
~~  - urdf
~~  - collada_urdf
~~  - gazebo_plugins
~~  - gazebo_ros
~~  - kdl_parser
~~  - robot_state_publisher
~~  - rviz
~~  - librviz_tutorial
~~  - rqt_rviz
~~  - rviz_plugin_tutorials
~~  - rviz_python_tutorial
~~  - urdf_tutorial
~~  - visualization_marker_tutorials
~~  - voxel_grid
~~  - costmap_2d
~~  - nav_core
~~  - base_local_planner
~~  - carrot_planner
~~  - clear_costmap_recovery
~~  - dwa_local_planner
~~  - move_slow_and_clear
~~  - navfn
~~  - rotate_recovery
~~  - move_base
~~  - xacro
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The packages or cmake arguments have changed, forcing cmake invocation

==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/catkin'
==> cmake /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release in '/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 5.1.0.5030040
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 5.1.0.5030040
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.5") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM) 
CMake Error at cmake/empy.cmake:28 (message):
  Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
  installing package 'python-empy'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/all.cmake:139 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  Command 'cmake /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && cmake /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

Command failed, exiting.
```

Here are the contents of the file -- "`catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`"

```
The system is: Darwin - 13.2.0 - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/3.0.0/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "/Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/3.0.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec3831956148/fast"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3831956148.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3831956148.dir/build
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3831956148.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3831956148.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3831956148
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3831956148.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3831956148.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3831956148  


Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec3164218406/fast"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/build
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3164218406
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3164218406   
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -o cmTryCompileExec3164218406 -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-236.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/


Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec3164218406/fast"]
  ignore line: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/build]
  ignore line: [/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1]
  ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3164218406]
  ignore line: [/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3164218406   ]
  ignore line: [Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  link line: [ "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -o cmTryCompileExec3164218406 -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld] ==> ignore
    arg [-demangle] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic] ==> ignore
    arg [-arch] ==> ignore
    arg [x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [-macosx_version_min] ==> ignore
    arg [10.9.0] ==> ignore
    arg [-syslibroot] ==> ignore
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTryCompileExec3164218406] ==> ignore
    arg [-search_paths_first] ==> ignore
    arg [-headerpad_max_install_names] ==> ignore
    arg [-v] ==> ignore
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3164218406.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lSystem] ==> lib [System]
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a] ==> lib [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  Library search paths: [;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib]
  Framework search paths: [;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/]
  remove lib [System]
  collapse lib [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  collapse library dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib]
  collapse framework dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks]
  implicit libs: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  implicit dirs: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib]
  implicit fwks: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks]


Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec2392446172/fast"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2392446172.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2392446172.dir/build
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2392446172.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2392446172.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec2392446172
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2392446172.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2392446172.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2392446172  


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec760356047/fast"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/build
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec760356047
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTryCompileExec760356047   
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -o cmTryCompileExec760356047 -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-236.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/


Parsed CXX implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec760356047/fast"]
  ignore line: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/build]
  ignore line: [/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/voladoddi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1]
  ignore line: [Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp]
  ignore line: [Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec760356047]
  ignore line: [/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/c++     -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTryCompileExec760356047   ]
  ignore line: [Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  link line: [ "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -o cmTryCompileExec760356047 -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld] ==> ignore
    arg [-demangle] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic] ==> ignore
    arg [-arch] ==> ignore
    arg [x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [-macosx_version_min] ==> ignore
    arg [10.9.0] ==> ignore
    arg [-syslibroot] ==> ignore
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTryCompileExec760356047] ==> ignore
    arg [-search_paths_first] ==> ignore
    arg [-headerpad_max_install_names] ==> ignore
    arg [-v] ==> ignore
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec760356047.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lc++] ==> lib [c++]
    arg [-lSystem] ==> lib [System]
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a] ==> lib [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  Library search paths: [;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib]
  Framework search paths: [;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/]
  remove lib [System]
  collapse lib [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  collapse library dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib]
  collapse framework dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks]
  implicit libs: [c++;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  implicit dirs: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib]
  implicit fwks: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks]
```

If there's anything I should be looking for to fix, please let me know and I'll ask further questions, if I get any, after following up on suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185808/building-catkin-workspace-on-mac-os-x-mavericks/) by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks all for helping out. I did try it out and I got stuck elsewhere. Installed a Ubuntu virtual machine and it has increased the speed of learning ROS by much.

---

Originally posted by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) with karma: 87 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0